# How to use lodash `value` and continue with chain?

Tags: lodash

I love lodash and I use it in many projects.

I always have this problem and I can't find a solution for it.

I would like to do something with lodash, save a temporary state, and continue.

For example lets assume I have `moviesList` which is a list of movies with their id and profit, and I want to

- index movies by their id and keep the result in `moviesById`
- filter profitable movies and keep the result in `overMillionProfit`

And I want to do so without breaking the chain. 
Something like (wishful thinking):

```
  var moviesList = [{id : 1}, {id:2}, ...];
  var moviesById = {};
  var overMillionProfit = [];
  _(moviesList)
      .keyBy('id')
      .do((unwrappedValue)=> moviesById = unwrappedValue)
      .values()
      .filter( (m) => m.profit > 1000000)
      .do((unwrappedValue) => overMillionProfit = unwrappedValue)
```

Currently, I find it necessary to break the chain like so:

```
  var moviesList = [{id : 1}, {id:2}, ...];
  var moviesById = _.keyBy(moviesList,'id');
  var overMillionProfit = _.filter(moviesList, ...);
```

Perhaps for this scenario it is better, but I want to be able to do it like the above in some cases.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_.tap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#tap) for that:

```js
var moviesList = [{id : 1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
  var moviesById;
  var overMillionProfit;
  var result = _(moviesList)
      .keyBy('id')
      .tap((unwrappedValue)=> moviesById = unwrappedValue)
      .values()
      .filter( (m) => m.id > 1)
      .tap((unwrappedValue) => overMillionProfit = unwrappedValue)
      .value();

console.log('moviesById\n', moviesById);
console.log('overMillionProfit\n', overMillionProfit);
console.log('result\n', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```